# Problem with citation on the following page

Tags: biblatex

I have a little problem: When I use the following code, the second of my citations ends up as a full citation after a second run of latex. I think it is because of that it is placed on a new page in the document - but I don't know how to fix this... Do you have the same problems using the code?

```
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@book{krotz2007,
 Address = {Wiesbaden},
 Author = {Krotz, Friedrich},
 Publisher = {VS Verlag},
 series = {Reihe: Medien, {Kultur}, {Kommunikation}},
 volume = {5},
 Title = {Mediatisierung: {Fallstudien} zum {Wandel} von {Kommunikation}},
 Year = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %<-- ergänzt
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   bibencoding=ascii,
   citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
   ibidtracker=true,
   pagetracker=true,
   maxnames=2,
   maxbibnames=25]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib} %<-- ergänzt

\begin{document}
\lipsum
Die Untersuchung des Mediatisierungsprozesses kann für Krotz nur sinnvoll durch den Einbezug sozialer Mikro-, Meso- und Makroebenen erfolgen. Auf der Makroebene haben Medien ganze Gesellschaften und Kulturen tiefgreifend durchdrungen und verändert. Mediatisierung hat aber auch entscheidenden Einfluss auf die Gestaltung von Institutionen und Organisationen, also auf Strukturen der Mesoebene gehabt, sowie auf die kommunikative Praxis von Individuen auf der Mikroebene. Deutlich wird daran, dass der Prozess der Mediatisierung erst aus einer historischen Perspektive wirklich deutlich hervortritt, die zudem soziale und kulturelle Entwicklungen berücksichtigt.

Die Untersuchung des Mediatisierungsprozesses kann für Krotz nur sinnvoll durch den Einbezug sozialer Mikro-, Meso- und Makroebenen erfolgen. Auf der Makroebene haben Medien ganze Gesellschaften und Kulturen tiefgreifend durchdrungen und verändert. Mediatisierung hat aber auch entscheidenden Einfluss auf die Gestaltung von Institutionen und Organisationen, also auf Strukturen der Mesoebene gehabt, sowie auf die kommunikative Praxis von Individuen auf der Mikroebene. Deutlich wird daran, dass der Prozess der Mediatisierung erst aus einer historischen Perspektive wirklich deutlich hervortritt, die zudem soziale und kulturelle Entwicklungen berücksichtigt.

Nach Krotz \parencite[S. 59]{krotz2007} drückt sich das zentrale Anliegen der Mediatisierungsforschung in der Frage aus,  wie sich Kommunikation und damit die Konstruktion von Alltag und sozialen Beziehungen, von Kultur und Gesellschaft verändern, wenn sich gesellschaftlich vorherrschende Formen von Kommunikation verändern. Entsprechend kann diese Fragestellung auch als Hintergrundfolie für die hier vorgenommene Analyse verstanden werden. Es geht einerseits um die Überprüfung der von Krotz aus der Mediatisierung abgeleiteten Hypothese, dass es zu einer  Zunahme von  Medien, Medienangeboten und Medienfunktionen  kommt, die unter anderem zu unterschiedlichen rezeptionalen, sozialen und kommunikativen Folgen führt. Eine dieser Folgen soll hier unter dem Schlagwort der informationellen Öffnung verhandelt werden. Orientiert man sich also an den zuvor identifizierten Kriterien, wäre der Prozess der informationellen Öffnung als Effekt der Mediatisierung in die Reihe der bereits oben genannten Metaprozesse zu integrieren. Dies soll jedoch erst nach der Untersuchung geschehen, die durch ihre politischen, technischen, ökonomischen, wissenschaftlichen, kulturellen und religiösen Kontextualisierungen erst die Voraussetzung für die Einordnung schafft \parencite[S. 34]{krotz2007}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: how to insert code properly? two methods: insert 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, making sure that there is a blank line above and also below the code block; or (usually easier) highlight (mouse over) the entire block of code, then click on the `{}` icon at the top of the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed find that the repeated citation (instead of 'ebd.'/'ibid.') is always the first on a new page. This is the default behaviour of `biblatex` where we have

```
\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
  {...}
```

in the definition of `cite` macros in `authoryear-icomp.cbx`.

It's not a bug, it's a feature! The idea is that a reader does not have to go back to the last page to see where 'ebd.'/'ibid.' refers to.

You can turn off this behaviour by turning off the page tracker with `pagetracker=false` (you have an explicit `pagetracker=true`, which is the default anyway). This will also have influence on other macros that use `\iffirstonpage`, notably the name dash in the bibliography.